# MKNetworkKit upload file in chunks or sections

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, nsurlconnection, mknetworkkit

I work on a photo viewing/uploading client for iOS. Our server team wants to switch over to a system where we would break the file into sections (suppose 50k), upload all the sections, then make a call to the server to assemble them.

My first questions is "What is this technique called?". I can't seem to find a good term to search on.

Second are there any libraries out there that are useful for creating the fragments, or will NSData's methods do what is necessary? I'm currently using MKNetworkKit to make all of our REST calls. I've seen some posts about this that use ASIHTTPRequest, but I'd like to just use one HTTP lib. Also, ASI is no longer in active development.